# program to check arithmetic progression from .txt file and print true/false

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that when a user enters a txt file, it reads the data and prints the file, and states if arithmetic progression is true.

example desired output

```
file: something.txt
[1,2,3,4] True
[3,4,7,7] False 
[2,4,6,8,10] True 
so on ..
```

I have attempted this but am not sure how to read through the file and achieve this desired result. My current code takes given values and prints the output below.

```
Source File Name: p3_v1.txt
True
False
```

See bellow my code.

```
name = input('Source File Name: ')

    def is_arithmetic(l):
        delta = l[1] - l[0]
        for index in range(len(l) - 1):
            if not (l[index + 1] - l[index] == delta):
                 return False
        return True

print(is_arithmetic([5, 7, 9, 11]))
print(is_arithmetic([5, 8, 9, 11]))
```

How am I able to change my code to print the contents of the txt file and print if each line is true or false?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the structure of your input file?

Comment: Hi @ edward the contents of the input file are as follows,

Comment: 2 4 6 8 10 12 14

Comment: 1 3 6 7 7 7 5 7

Comment: and so on.. the file has 5 lines with 4 - 5 numbers per line, sorry the formatting in the comments stuffed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work...

```
name = input('Source File Name: ')

def is_arithmetic(l):
    delta = l[1] - l[0]
    for index in range(len(l) - 1):
        if not (l[index + 1] - l[index] == delta):
            return l, False
    return l, True


# open the containing data
with open(name, 'rt') as txtfile:  

    # read in data and split into lines
    lines = txtfile.read().split('\n') 

#  iterate through the lines one at a time
for line in lines:  

    # convert to integers
    l = [int(i) for i in line.split(' ') if i.isdigit()]  

    # print the output of the is_arithmetic function for the line
    print(is_arithmetic(l))
```

Comment: Hi @ alexpdev unfortunately this code dosent work, i receive an error 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @Yakob  It works fine for me.  Try copying again, maybe you grabed the code before i was able to edit it

Comment: @ alexpdev the code has works but it isn't sorting the file properly .
the output shows 

Source File Name: P3_v1.txt
([2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 6, 46, 24, 35, 48, 88, 78, 68, 58], False)

I need the file to print all lines of file and all numbers in file and output each line with either true or false.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read a file you can use the Python built-in function ***open()*** function. documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). And this [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-open-function/) will also help

An Example Code:

```
name = input('Source File Name: ')
with open(name) as f:
    lines = f.read()
    print(lines)
    readlines = f.readlines()
    print(readlines)
```

Example Output

```
'1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n\n'
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '\n']
```

The **read()** function will give back the contents as a string.
and the **readlines()** would give back the lines as a list. You can use string manipulation to split the outputs and use int({varible}) to convert it to an Integer